# Why do I need to refresh the web page sometimes to see the data i retrieved from the api appear on my table? Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created an API using asp.net and I used angular as my front end. I am able to get the data just fine but sometimes I would need to refresh the page once or a few more times in order to actually see the data on my table. I have absolutely no idea why this might be happening. I hope the code I have inserted below will be enough to find the solution to my problem

Here is typescript file of my table component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import {DataService} from 'src/app/Services/data.service';
import {Anime} from 'src/app/Classes/anime';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from 'src/app/dialog/dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-anime-table',
  templateUrl: './anime-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./anime-table.component.css']
})

export class AnimeTableComponent implements OnInit {

  AnimeArray : Anime[] = [] ;
  data = false;

  constructor(private router : Router, 
    private dataService : DataService,
    private Dialog: MatDialog
    ) {}

  ngOnInit(){

    this.dataService.GetAnime()
    .subscribe(data =>  data.forEach(element => {
      var anime = new Anime();
      anime.AnimeID = element.AnimeID;
      anime.AnimeName = element.AnimeName;
      anime.Anime_Description = element.Anime_Description;
      this.AnimeArray.push(anime);
    }))


  }// ngOnInit

}//Export
```

Below is the html stuff

```
<br />
<button routerLink="/Dashboard" class="btn btn-primary">Go Home</button>
<button
  routerLink="/CreateAnime"
  class="btn btn-success"
  style="margin-left: 15px;"
>
  Add new Anime
</button>
<br />
<br />

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Anime ID</th>
      <th>Anime Name</th>
      <th>Anime Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let anime of AnimeArray">
      <td>{{ anime.AnimeID }}</td>
      <td>{{ anime.AnimeName }}</td>
      <td>{{ anime.Anime_Description }}</td>
      <td>
        <!-- <a [routerLink] = "['/Anime']" [queryParams] = "anime.AnimeID"  class="btn btn-success"> Edit </a>  -->
        <button (click)="EditAnime(anime.AnimeID)" class="btn btn-success">
          Edit
        </button>
        <button
          (click)="DeleteAnime(anime.AnimeID, anime.AnimeName)"
          style="margin-left: 15px;"
          class="btn btn-danger"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a piece of the dataservice that gets the Anime information from the API i created.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';  
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {Anime} from '../Classes/anime';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  url : string;
  header : any;
  option : any;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
    this.url = 'http://localhost:50484/api/Values/';
    const headerSettings: {[name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};  
    //this.header = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);
    this.header = {'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('UserToken')}

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization' : 'bearer '  + localStorage.getItem('UserToken')})
    this.option = {headers : headers};
  }
  GetAnime() : Observable<Anime[]> {
    console.log(this.header);
    const headers = {'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('UserToken')} 
    return this.http.get<Anime[]>(this.url + 'GetAllAnime/' , {headers});
  }
 } // data service
```

P.S I am currently not seeing any errors in the browser console, the cmd or in visual studio code

Comment: where to u fire to load data again ??

Comment: Are you not getting data anytime? How does it behave?Please provide more details or a [mcve] at stackBlitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try map data first and replace the entire array, instead of pushing in the array.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.GetAnime().subscribe(data => data =>
      (this.AnimeArray = data.map(element => {
        var anime = new Anime();
        anime.AnimeID = element.AnimeID;
        anime.AnimeName = element.AnimeName;
        anime.Anime_Description = element.Anime_Description;
        return anime;
      }))
    );
  } // ngOnInit
```